# Advice needed for mimicking Whatsapp registration

Tags: php, android, ios, cordova, whatsapp

I usually do web development on computers, and I have newly entered the realm of mobile development. The application I am currently working on requires the registration process to work exactly like Whatsapp, so essentially these are the steps.

1- User enters their phone number. 
2- When user submits their phone number, I have to send an SMS back to their phone with a registration code. 
3- User enters the registration code, if it matches, user is in. 
4- User doesn't have to login ever again.

Going to more details, this is how I suspect this should be implemented, and hopefully with your expertise I can get some advise.

1- I will be using phone gap, so a regular HTML form, referencing back to a PHP script.

2- This I am unsure of. What I think I can do is I can find out what the user's carrier is, and use the user's phone number @ carrier and just use the php mail function (015-1231234@carrier.com) But Whatsapp, Viber, etc don't ask for your carrier. Do you guys know how they were able to do that?

3- In my database table I have a registration code stored that is randomly generated by a php script. I store that in the DB, and I send it to the user. When the verifies the code, I just compare it with the table.

4- I actually don't know how to do that. Do smartphones operate on sessions, cookies, something else? How can I make it permanent? Ideally what I would like to have is a simple check before I display the index of the app. Something like:

```
if($_SESSION['userID']){
  //show protected page here
}
else {
  //user needs to register. Ideally only once in their lifetime. 
}
```